# Is it possible to install an early Core2 on an E7230 chipset?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-rec, requirements

I'm considering attempting to install a Xeon [3060](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27205)/[3070](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27206) onto an [ASUS P5MT-M](http://usa.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=ajHa5grlVqAtbKo8) motherboard.

ASUS and Intel don't say anything about this being supported, but I want to see if SU thinks it can still be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all your recent questions all about the same motherboard!?

Anyway, as I said in the previous question you asked - you may be able to if you reflash your BIOS, I managed to get it working - but I could swear that performance took a big hit.

If it isn't supported, I really would not risk it.

Comment: Haha, yeah. Somewhat different questions, all in the same context. It was worth asking, I think. I don't want to drop back down to 800FSB if I don't have to. But it looks like that's what I should realistically do.

Comment: It also looks like Xeon is not possible, since none of the pre-Core2 versions are LGA775.